# Cannot call ViewDebug.ExportedProperty methods

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and Java and don't understand something.  There are public methods in the View class that are prefixed with `@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")`.  For example:

```
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")
public boolean isLayoutRtl() {
    return (getLayoutDirection() == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
```

Why is it that Android classes derived from View can call these public methods, but classes in another package (such as mine) also derived from View, cannot see these public methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the whole method, comments included.

```
/**
 * Indicates whether or not this view's layout is right-to-left. This is resolved from
 * layout attribute and/or the inherited value from the parent
 *
 * @return true if the layout is right-to-left.
 *
 * @hide
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")
public boolean isLayoutRtl() {
    return (getLayoutDirection() == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
```

There is an `@hide` annotation, which means that the method is not part of the public Android API.

Luckily for you, the direction constants and `getLayoutDirection()` are already publicly available. It is trivial to copy this method in your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I find some public methods that are prefixes with `@hide`,but Android classes derived from View can call these public methods.  eg:

```
/**
 * Returns whether this View is accessibility focused.
 *
 * @return True if this View is accessibility focused.
 * @hide
 */
public boolean isAccessibilityFocused() {
    return (mPrivateFlags2 & PFLAG2_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) != 0;
}
```

I am a Android and Java beginner.